# Install drupal in a directory beside an existing website

Tags: apache, drupal, redirect, directory

I want to Install a drupal website on the server in a subdirectory to use some of it's features for my main website, I dont want the installation affect the current website in any way.

the actual reason for doing this is that for example I would be able to use news section of drupal for main website.

so for instance, I install drupal on "drupal" subdirectory like `www.mydomain.com/drupal` , then when I configure and run the news section it will be like `www.mydomain.com/drupal/news`, what I want is when a user goes to `www.mydomain.com/news`, it loads `www.mydomain.com/drupal/news` instead.

I'd really appreciate any proper approach and suggestions to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question that you want to have URLs like:

```
http://example.com/news/headline-test
```

But using Drupal's URL http://example.com/drupal/news/headline-test to provide the content of the first URL, you should use Apache rewrites.

Here is an example: 
Add this to your top .htaccess folder (http://example.com/.htaccess - not publicly accessible yes):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) drupal/news/$1
```

See the [Apache rewrite document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html) for more examples/help. 
Drupal cannot take over any folder if there is another file exists or it's pointing to another folder. But in this case, both of your `http://example.com/drupal/news/headline-test` and `http://example.com/news/headline-test` URLs will show the same content. 
Do not edit Drupal's `$base_url` setting. Let Drupal figure it out. Also, add some `robots.txt` disallows to prevent content duplication. Block drupal's native URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/redirect).

OR

Create a custom module with [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) implementation

```
function MY_MODULE_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['news'] = array(
        'title' => 'news redirect',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
        'page arguments' => array('drupal/news'),
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Muhammad, but I think it works only for drupal, What I want is to redirect my existing website URL, to drupal'

Comment: I worked with the module before and I'm familiar with It's functionality, I can redirect any internal URL from www.mydomain.com/drupal/... to another internal URL's on my drupal installation, that's not what I'm looking for, I want to redirect an external URL (from my main website) to a specific drupal URL

Comment: It still does the same thing that module does, it redirect internal drupal path. thanks anyway for your efforts

Comment: When `/drupal/news` URL is requested, it redirects the user to the `drupal/drupal/news` page.